# Convention or IC for dynamically switching multiple paths on a PCB?

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, schematics, routing

I'm trying to create programmable circuit paths (controlled via mcu), where my program can arbitrarily connect **N** pins on one side of the circuit/pcb to **N** pins on the other side.  Ideally, this would work as a "pass-through" (minimal resistance) and have a minimum rating of -30V/+30V and 10A of current.

Physically, the pins on an external connector would connect to specific parts of the pcb. Ground pin to ground rail. Power pin to  power management, and so on. I'd like to be able to configure/control this via an mcu.

Does an IC for this already exist, or a convention for doing this?

I've thought about using an **N<sup>2</sup>** transistor/switch array, but that seems like it might cause cross-talk/interference and be generally inefficient. I was also suggested multiplexers but I couldn't find any that can handle my specific voltage and amperage.

Also, this "programmable path circuit" would have power, grounds, and data paths running through it. I usually see to keep power and data separate. Assuming this can be done, would there be any significant issues in routing power and data paths so close together?

Comment: 10A and 30V upwards, have you considered relays?

Comment: @Justme That may be a better solution than transistors for the high ratings, but it still leaves the problem of needing **N<sup>2</sup>** relays. I'm guessing there's probably some way to reduce that via permutation, but still seems inefficient and lot.

Comment: It’s an N-squared problem so there’s really no getting away from having that number of switches, be they relays or semiconductors.  Using multi-pole relays will save a certain amount, 4-pole are relatively common.

Comment: Possibly with a binary tree of changeover relays you could more or less halve the number of relays, although the current path would be through several sets of contacts.

Comment: What is the exact purpose of this device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for analog crosspoint switches. But you'll have a hard time finding something that fulfills everything you want.

If you want something monolythic you'll have to reduce your power requirements (10A is a lot of current) or switch to a discrete solution.

For a crosspoint fabric where you can switch every input to every output you need a fabric of number of inputs multiplied by number of outputs.

If you want minimum resistance and high current capability you won't get around using relais (keep in mind the low switching speed and limited cycles relays have). If you want 8 inputs and 8 outputs you need 64 relais. That's a lot of space and quite expensive.

If you're ok with 1-2V of voltage drop you can use electronic switches (thyristors for example) but with 10 Amps you'll have 10-20W of waste heat per channel. Getting rid of that much power takes a beefy cooling solution which is not small nor cheap. But you get relatively high switching speeds and basically unlimited switching cycles.

If you can further reduce your requirements and can live with 150 Ohms of resitance in on case (and therefore very limited current because otherwise the stuff gets too hot) you can look into analog crosspoint switches.

Keep in mind, that with all the discreete solutions you still need a way to control it which takes energy as well...

There is a nice one for 24V with 16 inputs and 16 outputs. for example the [AD75019](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad75019.html) by Analog Devices.

Comment: Thanks for explaining different possible situations.
I'll mark your reply as the correct answer because it will probably be more relevant for future viewers.
However, I have come to the conclusion that what I'm attempting to do is not currently practical. A digitally controlled DIP switch with no current leakage and no power to heat inefficiency (electro-mechanical), with the long lasting lifetime of solid state switches, that can handle 30V and 10A, all at a cheap cost to boot.

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for was a [Multistage Interconnect Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multistage_interconnection_networks) topology configuration. More specifically, the Benes network layout. This will allow me to create programmable paths. I haven't decided on the switch yet.

Comment: JollyRoger - Hi, Since you have written this as an answer, it seems like you have finished with your question. It would help readers if you can [edit] your answer & add a few lines about *why* that is the solution for you, since "link-only" answers are discouraged here. That's because the actual answer isn't *here* and the information at that link could change / disappear etc. || Once you have made your answer as good as you need it to be, please consider [accepting an answer](/help/someone-answers), either [yours](/help/self-answer) or another one, to effectively close the topic. Thanks.

Comment: I think since the question asked for an IC this isn't an answer.

Comment: I stated "or a convention". This would be that convention.